# form not closing immediately after listening to FormClosed event

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have two windows forms. I am calling the second form from a button click on the first form using Form.Show(). I want to show a messagebox after the form is closed. I subscribed to the FormClosed event but the form only closes after the messagebox is displayed.

any reasons why this happens?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 fr2 = new Form2();
    fr2.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(fr2_FormClosed);
    fr2.Show(); 
}  

void fr2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("second form closed");
}
```

Comment: In you code snippet you have subscribed to `FormClosing` event not `FormClosed`!

Comment: that was typo..i tried both events :)  corrected now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the event fires before the form is removed from the screen and `MessageBox.Show(` blocks until you press the ok button.

Here is from the decompiled source code of the .NET framework for the private function `WmClose` which handles the closing of a form.

```
private void WmClose(ref Message m)
{
      //Snip...

      FormClosedEventArgs e3 = new FormClosedEventArgs(this.CloseReason);
      this.OnClosed((EventArgs) e3);
      this.OnFormClosed(e3);
      base.Dispose();
}

protected virtual void OnFormClosed(FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
  Application.OpenFormsInternalRemove(this);
  FormClosedEventHandler closedEventHandler = (FormClosedEventHandler) this.Events[Form.EVENT_FORMCLOSED];
  if (closedEventHandler == null)
    return;
  closedEventHandler((object) this, e); //This line is what calls fr2_FormClosed
}
```

The form is still visible on the screen until `base.Dispose()` is called and the code does not return from `this.OnFormClosed(e3);` until your code returns from `fr2_FormClosed`.

The easiest work around is defer the showing of the message box by putting it on the message queue via a [`BeginInvoke(`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.begininvoke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
void fr2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show("second form closed");
    }));
}
```

This now puts the action of showing the message box on to the message pump queue and continues on its work of closing `Form2`, once it has finished closing it will look for more work to do on the message queue and then display the message box.